# Simple Flask-SocketIo with "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python, flask-socketio

I'm following the Flask-SocketIo documentation (https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and the example code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     socketio.run(app)
```

Is giving me this error:

```
    self.async = None
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Every thing is up-to-date, thus I think the error is from the official package. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Update your Flask-SocketIO.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was my pip was installing old version of  Flask-SocketIO and I needed to install werkzeug with command (pip install -U werkzeug)